# Utility: Tabbed Windows

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, tools

Am looking for a tool that accommodate any programs/application window(not limited to terminals) in a tabbed container.In other words, a tabbed windows tool close to something like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r_n0lfn8aM

Am happy with the unity desktop, would like not to change unity desktop just for simple requirements.

Appreciate all your suggestions.

Comment: What I am guessing is that you want a tool that groups windows together. There's nothing like that to the best of my knowledge. There are  tiling window managers , so you could look into that. As far as simple tool for grouping windows together and using that to switch windows, take a look at this: http://imgur.com/a/cYwIX   Let me know if this indicator would be something you'd like.

Comment: Serg, I work on few simulators(application, terminals, etc.,), read some documents, web browser activities. All the above activities goes hand in hand. Its quite annoying every time changing workspace and search required window in the screen. So I prefer a tabbed windows to accommodate all the above in one container.

Comment: Well, as I said, to my knowledge there's no application like that. Give tiling window managers a try. `i3` or `xmonad` or `pekwm` for example

Comment: Thanks Serg, Am worried since the inception of Ubutu 12.04LTS this requirement is left unnoticed by the developers community. This is just an attempt to make the developers community to aware,  this requirement is long awaited. May be you can help me to refer this requirement to them.